# Segfault on second iteration of while loop

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

if I comment out ml_add(), the code works fine, but when that function runs, the first item completes but the second iteration runs into a segmentation fault at `bucket = list->buckets[bin];` in the `ml_add()` function. Did I do something wrong there?

```
int main() {
  FILE *fPtr = fopen("S.txt", "r");
  MList *ml = ml_create();
  printf("Creation OK\n\n");

  MEntry *m2;
  int i = 1;
  while ((m2 = me_get(fPtr)) != NULL) {
    unsigned long int hash = me_hash(m2, ml->numbuckets);
    printf("Index: %d, Hash: %d\n", i, hash);
    ml_add(&ml, m2);
    me_print(m2, fPtr);
    i++;
  }

  return 0;
}

/* ml_create  - creates a new mailing list
              - returns pointer to start of mailing list*/
MList *ml_create(void) {
  MList *ml = malloc(sizeof(MList));

  ml->numbuckets = NUMBUCKETS; // random initial number
                               // will increment once a bucket is full

  ml->buckets = calloc(ml->numbuckets, sizeof(Bucket));

  // init Buckets
  int b;
  for (b=0; b<ml->numbuckets; b++) {
    ml->buckets = malloc(sizeof(Bucket));
    Bucket *bk = malloc(sizeof(Bucket));
    bk->size = 0;
    bk->entries = calloc(BUCKETSIZE, sizeof(MEntry));
    ml->buckets[b] = bk;
    printf("***Bucket %d with capacity %d set at size %d\n",
            b, BUCKETSIZE, ml->buckets[b]->size);
  }

  return ml;
}

int ml_add(MList **ml, MEntry *me) {
  printf("***ml_add() called\n");
  // get [ml]
  MList *list = *ml;
  // get hash of [me] -- index of bucket to add to
  unsigned long int bin = me_hash(me, list->numbuckets);
  printf("***hash/bin acquired: %d\n", bin);

  // add to list's bucket[bin]
  Bucket *bucket;
  if ( (bucket = malloc(sizeof(Bucket))) == NULL)
    printf("malloc failed.\n");
  bucket = list->buckets[bin];
  printf("***bucket %d acquired, size = %d\n", bin, bucket->size);
  // add to end of bucket
  bucket->entries[bucket->size] = malloc(sizeof(MEntry));
  printf("*****malloc ok\n");
  bucket->entries[bucket->size] = me;
  printf("***Add to bucket %d at index %d ok\n", bin, bucket->size);
  bucket->size++;
  printf("***Bucket %d size now: %d\n\n", bin, bucket->size);
}
```

Comment: The `bucket = list->buckets[bin];` statement is wrong: you allocate the memory and immediately lose it by overwriting the pointer to the allocated area. What do you want to do?

Comment: @GMichael wow okay that fixed it O___O thanks!

Comment: the posted code is missing the needed `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h> statements.   The posted code is missing the needed prototype statements for the functions.  The posted code is missing the definition of the `MList` and `MEntry`  and `Bucket`.  The posted code is missing the definition of the value: `NUMBUCKETS`.   Strongly suggest adding additional code block with the corrected code.